# Profiling Python containing Dask parallelization

Tags: python, profiling, dask

I've implemented dask.delayed() to parallelize my project, and as a result I no longer get useful information from profiling my project with cProfile - most of the time in the profile is now accounted for as `{method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}` which doesn't tell me anything about the time taken by the actual functions being called.

Short of re-writing the script to temporarily disable Dask, is there another method of profiling that would give information about the run times of the functions being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the distributed scheduler, and the profiling tab of its dashboard. The details are in [this documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html). Note that the profiler is *statistical*: it samples the call stacks of each worker thread on a regular schedule, and builds the display from that information.